# implement cURL command in C# (synchronous, post, TLS 1,2)

Tags: c#, curl, tls1.2

Here's a generic cURL command to copy a csv file from a server to c:\temp.

curl.exe --data "ARG1=value&ARG2=value" "https://some.server.com/data.csv" > "c:\temp\data.csv"

How would you code this a synchronous method in C# using a post method and TLS 1.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fiddling found this to work:

```
using System.Net.Http;
...
var values  = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "arg1", "value1" },  { "arg2", "value2" } };
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; // enable TLS 1.2
HttpResponseMessage responseMsg = new HttpClient().PostAsync(@"http://some.server.com/data.csv", content).Result;
if (responseMsg.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK) throw new Exception("err msg");
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\data.csv", responseMsg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
...
```

This code worked for me (I can't show the actual site).  The site in question is a data vendor who used to accept simple HTTP GET requests but is now switching to POST with SSL and TSL 1.2 in order to comply with EU rules.

I am not claiming that this code is robust, thread safe, or anything like that.  Just that I got it working.  So that's a start.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] data;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
  data = client.DownloadData("https://some.server.com/data.csv?arg1=value&ARG2=value");
}
File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\temp\data.csv", data);
```

Comment: needs to be a post method.

Comment: Formerly used VBA WinHTTP request, but there doesn't seem to be a way to set the WinHttpRequestOption_SecureProtocols parameter to 2048 for TLS 1.2.  Other than that this VBA  would work:

Comment: Set objHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
   ///        Call objHttp.Open("POST", "https://some.server.com/data.csv", False)
////    Call objHttp.Send("Arg1=value&Arg2=value...")